# How to gsub a word for its second and later occurrence R

Tags: r, gsub

I want to replace the word 'with' with a blank space (' ') in a string of words. There are many occurrences of 'with' in the string and I want to keep the first occurrence and replace all others.

I have tried using gsub and regex but can't seem to get it right.

```
string <- gsub('with.*?','\\1 ',string)
```

e.g.

```
string<- c('I want to, keep the first with with with with with with in this string')
```

expected outcome: 
string <- I want to, keep the first with  in this string

Answer (score 6):

We can use

```
gsub("(\\w+ )\\1+", "\\1", string)
#[1] "I want to, keep the first with in this string"
```

or if it needs to be a specific word

```
gsub("(with )\\1+", "\\1", string)
#[1] "I want to, keep the first with in this string"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the first `with` with `WITH`, then replace each occurrence of `with` with a space.  Finally revert `WITH` to `with`.  The `\\b` match boundaries so that, for example, the `with` in `forthwith` would not get replaced.

```
sub("\\bWITH\\b", "with", gsub("\\bwith\\b", " ", sub("\\bwith\\b", "WITH", string)))
## [1] "I want to, keep the first with           in this string"
```